# In VB.NET How to Convert MST Time Zone value to another Time Zone?

Tags: vb.net, time, timezone

I have time values from my db in Mountain Standard Time.  I would like to know how to best accurately convert those values into a user's timezone.

I have a function like this(passes in format and a time in MST):

```
   Dim localZone As TimeZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone
   If localZone Is Nothing Or localZone.StandardName = "Mountain Standard Time" Then
       Return DateTimeInMST.ToString(format) & " MST"
   Else
       Return (Return Value here in the user's timezone.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `TimeZone` is recommended in the docs.  Using that, you could do something like this:

```vb
Dim mst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mountain Standard Time")
Dim local = TimeZoneInfo.Local
Dim localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeInMST, mst, local)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ConvertTime method to convert from the Mountain Standard Time to the local time of the user. Your code would look like this:

```
Dim localZone As TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.Local
   If localZone Is Nothing Or localZone.StandardName = "Mountain Standard Time" Then
       Return DateTimeInMST.ToString(format) & " MST"
   Else
       Return System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeInMST, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mountain Standard Time"), TimeZoneInfo.Local)
```

Find more info in the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).